# Connect sharepoint list with access front end

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

I have a access DB i have splitted it into front end and backend two files.

I have migrated the backend to sharepoint list, now i want to configure the sharepoint list with the access front end. Is there an option for that? If you let me know the procedure that will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup. In your Access front-end (assuming you have 2010):

1. Go to **External Data**
2. Under **Import & Link**, go to **More**
3. Choose **SharePoint List**
4. Link to your tables of choice.

Does that help?